# "Not found" when trying to access deployed Heroku PERN application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, heroku

I followed the steps in a tutorial on how to deploy a PERN app and when I do "heroku open", I get "Not found" on the page and "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" in the console.

Any idea what the reason might be? I have tried a million different things and nothing solves the issue.

Comment: You can run heroku logs —tail -a your_app to monitor what happens. But if 404 is returned, then there is no such route on backend, right? Which actually shouldnt be issue with heroku

Comment: But my apps work perfectly locally. How is it not Heroku then?

Comment: You need to share more information… what about other backend routes? Have you tried it  - is 404 not found response for all of them? I just deployed express app on heroku few days ago and all was good. Have you configured env variables from your react app towards backend app?

Comment: I was finally able to deploy all my apps. First a React-only one, then a React/Express one and lastly the PERN one. They were obviously increasingly difficult to deploy. Honestly, I feel like Heroku docs are really lacking. I was just lucky to find a tutorial that told you the right thing to do, after watching a thousand others that didn't help at all. In the end, getting the job done took many less lines than the ones most tutorials would have me insert.

Comment: i don't know how you do it, but for me it was 2 apps to deploy - React and Node (express). Postgres database add-on is attached to Node app on heroku. Its a bit tricky to find out how to setup database on free plan (without certificates), while with first next paid plan i think heroku handles it automatically.